# The "No new notifications" notification happens even after I turn off notifications in Windows 11. How to turn it off?

Tags: windows-11, notifications, notification-area, popups, windows-11-v22h2

I have turned off notifications in Windows 11.
[image]

However, I still get the "No new notifications" popup when my mouse is near the right bottom corner.

[image]

Occasionally, this is on top of the scroll bar bottom arrow & makes it difficult to click - is there a way to avoid the "No new notifications" notification - it doesn't make sense to have it since I am anyway never going to get new notifications.

I am running Windows 11 Home Single Language 22H2 OS Build 22621.2715

UPDATE: It happens even after I turn "Do not disturb" on

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some notifications may happen - updates, restarts, and like.

In your case, the settings are (to me) opposed.

The first setting (top one) says Do Not Get Notifications from Apps and Other Senders. You have this OFF.  Fine.

The second setting (next one down) says you wish to be disturbed by notifications (it is OFF). If you wish Do Not Disturb to be enabled, the turn this setting ON.

*These are the two main settings. For you Notifications OFF and Do Not Disturb ON.*

You can fine tune the Do Not Disturb settings with the next two settings (Do not disturb settings and Priority settings).

Setting these two as described will reduce many notifications.

You will have to play with the settings because (a) there is more than one notification setting and (b) some notifications will come (updates, restart and like notifications.

Here is a screen shot of what you need to do.

[image: Windows Notifications]

Comment: This still won’t prevent Windows telling you there are no notifications. What the author wants is to essentially disable the Notification Center, since, that’s the only way to disable the “no notifications” popup. I know no way to do that.

Comment: One cannot disable ALL notifications and I said that.  But turning "Get Notifications" OFF and Do Not Disturb ON will reduce many notifications.

Comment: It happens even after I turn "Do not disturb" on - https://imgur.com/7nKq07D.png

Comment: The 2 main settings are Notifications and Do Not Disturb. You have Notifications OFF and Do Not Disturb ON. This should reduce notifications - you cannot eliminate them. I have Notifications ON and Do Not Disturb OFF (the reverse of you) and manage details in the detailed settings and I do not get many notifications/.  If this is not working as designed, something else has gone wrong.

Comment: I added a screen of the details location to help you @user93353

Comment: All my app notifications are off. And I don't think it's relevant because none of the apps show the "No new notifications" notification anyway. It's the system which shows it. The notification I want to eliminate is "No new notifications" as stated in the question. That's the only notification this question is about

Comment: There appears to be something wrong with your OS

Comment: It's a brand new install of the OS & I see in it other machines also. Just take your mouse to the bottom right hand corner.

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. I get less than 1 notification per day long term average and do not see this as an issue of any kind. I manage individual apps as I showed after a new install or a feature update.

Comment: When you open a notification, don't forget to clear it (X top right of the notification) and if you do not want that one again, turn off either while dealing with the notification, or as I showed in the answer.

Comment: though I was thinking of disable notifications facility from services.msc. but to echo Ramhound's comment, there is no way to disable notifications pop-ups, would you consider a workaround by adjust _Focus assist_ to _Priority only_?

Comment: Focus Assist will not tun notifications off but try to see if it reduces some.